# Use directory from main setup in merge module

Tags: wix, merge-module

I need to install the content of a merge module to a special (sub) folder set in the main setup.
Currently all our setups contain a directory with a special name (ex. "PROGDIR") and we use InstallShield's Direct Editor so give the directory in the merge module the same name.
During merging the directory in the merge module gets overwritten/discarded (call it magic, call it a hack, it's ugly ...).

This solution is quite fragile, as whenever you touch the merge module in InstallShield and fiddle with components or use the "Files and Folders" tab, IS appends the merge module guid to the directory identifier and it all stops working (PROGDIR -> PROGDIR.1234ABC...)

I now want to move our merge modules step by step to WiX. The main setups can not yet follow and must not need to change.

Can I prevent WiX from automatically adding a guid to the directory identifier to use the same hack as before?
Or is there a better, cleaner solution without changing the main setups?

I have looked into the Substitution element, but can not wrap my head around how this would work. If this could help somehow I would appreciate an example ...

Comment: Would you be interested in a 30 minute screen sharing session?  I have some custom tooling and patterns / templates that should make all this easier for you.  Google me for my email.

Comment: Unfortunately the powers that be have not given setups a high (or any) priority - which is what lead us into the current mess, but won't change soon. I'll probably go for the simplest solution and hope to clean up should WiX get established. "Simplest solution" being the deprecated and spec-violating IgnoreModularization element. Yeah ...

Comment: Seriously, a 30 minute screen share would teach you so much that your problem won't seem so massive anymore.  Be a professional and make it a priority for yourself.